Function field of a curve over $\mathbb F_q$: why do valuation rings correspond to closed points?
Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb F_q$ given by $f\in \mathbb F_q[x,y]$ a prime polynomial. Then we can consider the function field in one variable $\mathbb F_q(C)/\mathbb F_q$, where $\mathbb F_q(C)$ is the fraction field of the domain $\mathbb F_q[C]$. How can we prove the correspondence between the closed points of $C$ (orbits of points of $C(\overline{\mathbb F_q})$ by $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_q}/\mathbb F_q)$) and the places/valuation rings of the function field? By a valuation ring over $\mathbb F_q(C)/\mathbb F_q$ I mean an intermediate ring $\mathcal O$ such that there exists $t\in\mathcal O$ such that for every $z\in \mathbb F_q(C)$ there exists $u\in\mathcal O^\times$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$: $z=ut^n$; furthermore, $\mathcal O=\{ut^n:\;u\in\mathcal O^\times,\;\;n\geq 0\}$.
I've been looking for proofs of this but I can't seem to find them, or they have slightly different hypothesis.

Matsumura and IIRC also Stichtenoth define a valuation ring slightly differently: $\mathcal{O}$ needs to contain $\Bbb{F}_q$ and furthermore for all $z\in\Bbb{F}_q(\mathcal{C})$ either $z\in\mathcal{O}$ or $z^{-1}\in\mathcal{O}$. Your definition is that of a discrete valuation ring (=DVR). It is a theorem that all the valuation rings of $\Bbb{F}_q(\mathcal{C})$ are DVRs. May be that definition of a valuation ring is easier to work with?

Yes, I have seen that definition too (tbh I was mostly working with that one because I was reading Stichtenoth). Even with that definition I can't prove what I asked. I know that for a closed point I can define a ring $\mathcal O$ (ring of regular functions at the given point) that is contained in $\mathbb F_q(\mathcal C)$, and I know that this ring is Noetherian and local, but I can't prove that it's maximal ideal is principal to conclude it is a DVR. Viceversa, given a DVR in $\mathbb F_q(\mathcal C)$ I have no idea how you would get to a point.

Over a more interesting base field $k$, one should require that the base field $k$ is inside the valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$. Here, as Jyrki Lahtonen points out in the comments, it is automatic. The following will actually show that for a smooth  projective curve $C\to\operatorname{Spec} k$, the valuation rings of $k(C)$ containing $k$ are precisely the local rings of closed points. (Technicality for those who like them: smooth can be weakened to regular.)
In one direction, if $c\in C$ is a closed point, then $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ is a regular noetherian local domain of dimension one, and therefore a DVR. It contains $\Bbb F_q$, and has field of fractions $\Bbb F_q(C)$, so it is a valuation ring of $\Bbb F_q(C)/\Bbb F_q$.
In the other direction, since $C\to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_q$ is projective, hence proper, we may use the valuative criteria of properness and a characterization of morphisms from a valuation ring:

Valuative Criteria for Properness (Hartshorne theorem II.4.7) Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of finite type, with $X$ noetherian. Then $f$ is proper iff for every valuation ring $R$ with field of fractions $K$ and every diagram of the form $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} K @>>> X\\
@VVV @VV{f}V \\
\operatorname{Spec} R @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$ there is a unique morphism $\operatorname{Spec} R\to X$ making the diagram commute.


Characterization of morphisms from a valuation ring (Hartshorne lemma II.4.4) Let $R$ be a valuation ring of a field $K$. To give a morphism of $\operatorname{Spec} K$ to a scheme $X$ is equivalent to giving a point $x_1\in X$ and an inclusion of fields $k(x_1)\subset K$; to give a morphism of $\operatorname{Spec} R\to X$ is equivalent to giving two points $x_0,x_1$ in $X$ with $x_0$ a specialization of $x_1$, and an inclusion of fields $k(x_1)\subset K$, such that $R$ dominates the local ring of $x_0$ on the subscheme $\overline{\{x_1\}}$ equipped with the reduced induced structure.

Taking $R=\mathcal{O}$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_q$, $X=C$, and $f$ the structure morphism, as $\Bbb F_q \subset \mathcal{O}$ and $\operatorname{Frac} \mathcal{O}=\Bbb F_q(C)$, we can take $\operatorname{Spec} R\to\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb F_q$ to be the spectrum of the natural inclusion and $\operatorname{Spec} K\to X$ as the natural inclusion of the generic point to get the following diagram: $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} K @>>> C\\
@VVV @VV{f}V \\
\operatorname{Spec} R @>>> \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_q
\end{CD}$$
Since a proper morphism is projective, there exists a unique morphism $\operatorname{Spec} R\to X$ making the diagram commute. Since $\operatorname{Spec} K$ picks out the generic point $\eta$ of $C$, the inclusion $k(\eta)\subset K$ is the identity, and $C$ is exactly the closure of $\eta$ with the reduced induced structure, this morphism $\operatorname{Spec} R\to X$ is equivalent to a choice of closed point $c\in C$ so that $R$ dominates $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$. But valuation rings are maximal elements for local rings contained in a field under the relation of domination, so since $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ is also a valuation ring, we must have $R=\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$.

For the first direction I had seen that $\mathcal O_{C,c}$ had those properties, but I couldn't prove that it was regular and of dimension one, how can I prove that? The other direction might take me a little more to read so I'll check it out later. Thank you!!

@mrod1605 If $x\in X$ is a closed point in an integral scheme of finite type over a field, then $\dim\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\dim X$ (ref). This can be generalized. Next, if $X$ is smooth over a field, it is regular (ref).

Good job! I'm actually not sure whether we need to require the full field of constants to be included? I now vaguely recall that the elements algebraic (over the prime field) would be included in all the valuation rings (as they tend to be integrally closed).

@JyrkiLahtonen ah, you're right, in this case it's automatic. But for some more interesting fields to work over it might happen that we need to enforce that the base field is contained in the valuation ring, see here for a recent question about this.

@mrod1605 Any other questions? I notice we're getting close to the end of the bounty period.
